# Change PDFBox logging level using logback

Tags: spring-boot, logback, pdfbox, apache-tika, apache-commons-logging

I have a java app that is running on spring boot.
I'm using tika which in turn uses pdfbox.
I'm using logback as my logging implementation with slf4j.
I know that pdfbox uses apache commons logging.
I'm trying to disable the change the logging level to FATAL like so

```
<logger name="org.apache.pdfbox" level="FATAL"/>
```

The problem is that it still doesn't change the level.
I've run this with a debugger. I'm inspecting the logger that pdfbox uses and the results are

```
result = SLF4JLocationAwareLog
name = org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine
logger.level = null
logger.loggerContext = ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default]
```

By logger context, I understand that it is indeed using logback, but the configs are not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question and hope that someone will find it useful.
The reason that the `logger.level` was null is because I didn't specify anything, so it got it from the parent logger. The `FATAL` didn't work because the highest level is not `FATAL` but `ERROR`.

http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/Level.html

When I changed it to error everything worked as expected.